# how to fix this error : - failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operationAt line:1 char:147

Tags: c, if-statement

i cannot understand this error and i cannot faced this type of error.
i got this error from the terminal

```
Program 'practice_Q.6' failed to run: No application is associated 
with the specified file for this operationAt line:1 char:91
+ ... ) { gcc practice_Q.6.c -o practice_Q.6 } ; if ($?) { 
.\practice_Q.6 }
+
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:91
+ ... ) { gcc practice_Q.6.c -o practice_Q.6 } ; if ($?) { 
.\practice_Q.6 }
+
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], Applicati  
   onFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

hope you can help me in this error. :)**strong text**

Comment: You have `gcc` GNU C Compiler on your machine?

Comment: Don't name scripts or executables with non-standard suffixes (like `.6`). Windows uses the suffix to find out the type of the file.

Comment: On another note, please don't spam irrelevant or even completely wrong tags on your questions. It makes people less inclined to help you.